# CUDA OutOfMemory Error on Second Inference Nemo Model

Tags: pytorch

After the second inference on a moderately long sequence, or the third inference on short sequences, I will encounter the OutOfMemory CUDA error. The inferences before then are without issue. I am using the FastPitch model and following the Nvidia tutorial on inference directly.

Answer (score 0):

Possibilities:

1. Memory allocated for the model's intermediate computations was not fully released after the second inference, which caused a memory fragmentation issue that eventually led to the OutOfMemory error on the third inference.

Workaround :  Try releasing all memory resources allocated by the model after each inference by calling

> torch.cuda.empty_cache()

2. The short sequence used in the third inference may have required more memory for some reason, such as having more unique tokens or requiring more intermediate computations, than the long sequence used in the second inference.

Workaround: Try reducing the sequence length for the third inference to decrease the memory requirements.

Finally, you can try using mixed-precision training and inference, which uses lower-precision floating-point representations to reduce memory usage without sacrificing accuracy. FastPitch supports mixed-precision training, can try using the torch.cuda.amp package to enable mixed-precision training.